# Lua simple mouse press macro

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

i want when  i press left click to automatically press left click  until  i release it//i get error attempt to call upvalue 'mouse_event' (a nil value)
Can i do this somehow or can i do this with left click starting a keyboard macro instead of a mouseclick?

```
local mouse_event = mouse_event

if IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then

    repeat

        for i = 1,100000000000,1 do /*2 secs leftclick*/
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN) 
            sleep(50)
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP)
        end  

    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)

end
```

error attempt to call upvalue 'mouse_event' (a nil value)

Comment: In other words, you want to simulate multiple mouse button clicks while you keep mouse button down? You can start playing macro on press event and abort the macro on release event.

Comment: thx but how do i do this im a bit noob and why does it show me this erroe: attempt to call upvalue 'mouse_event' (a nil value)

Comment: We would need to see the whole code, including how mouse_event is defined. Also, you need to edit your code for readability. If you didn't copy/paste, you should copy/paste. As it stands right now, it'd throw up many errors (you don't have a space before 'then', comments do not start with `/` but rather `--`, you have a floating `until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)`). Once you've made those changes to readability and shown us how mouse_event is created/called initially, we might be able to offer more insight.

Comment: @nektarios - You don't need Lua here.  Create a macro which presses and releases mouse button.  Set repeat mode for this macro "while pressed".  Bind this macro to mouse button.  Lua is needed if you want sometimes turn this functionality on, and sometimes turn it off.

Comment: @Josh the question is taged showing the lua used is the logitech lua api which is not a stock lua version. iirc they changed comments to allow `//`  and `/*`

Comment: `mouse_event` is WinAPI function.  It's absent in LGS.   Use `PressMouseButton` and `ReleaseMouseButton` instead.

Comment: @Nifim It wasn't tagged that when I commented, so I wasn't aware. Interesting, though.

Comment: @Nifim - `//` and `/*` in LGS script generate compilation error for me.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ah yes you're right, i appear to have been thinking of `garry's mod`'s glua. I hope that is the right Egor there appears to be 2 different ones in these comments